# How do i get menu events from a menu item in the system menu of a console window?

Tags: c++, windows, console, menu, systemmenu

I have added a menu item to the SystemMenu of the console window of my application which i created using the `AllocConsole()` function. but I could not figure out how to process the events for the menu items I've added.

How can i process those menu events?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Did you try overriding window proc of the console window? ie once you have obtained the window handle with [GetConsoleWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683175%28VS.85%29.aspx) and then hooked its window proc with [SetWindowLongPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644898%28VS.85%29.aspx), you have to listen the [WM_SYSCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646360%28VS.85%29.aspx) message. See this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/MenusForBeginners.aspx#systemmenu) on how to process menu items from system menu.

Comment: Yeah i tried that.But i get an ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED when i try to subclass the console window

Comment: According to this message http://groups.google.com/group/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/msg/e98bac69a7052d9b, you can't subclas console window. Also you can try using a window hok http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28VS.85%29.aspx. The last option is to override the window proc using a trampoline, but I think that doing this is too far, just for adding a few menuitems.